# android: after async process get data back from onPostExecute to view OR pass view to onPostExecute

Tags: android, asynchronous, textview

i am trying to add extra input fields on the fly to my view.

i first read json string from url with an async funct and map this dynamically to an object with a hasmap with GSON.

next i want to iterate the hashmap to create and add the input fields:

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

     TextView view =  (TextView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);// is this the correct way to get view?

    new loadTemplateAttributes(view).execute();// android studio complains about passing view here

   .. snip...

    class loadTemplateAttributes extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap> {

    HashMap mymap;

    .. snip...

 protected void onPostExecute(HashMap mymap) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        Iterator it = mymap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String name = (String) pair.getKey();
            TemplateAttribureProperties t = (TemplateAttribureProperties) pair.getValue();
            String type = t.getType();
            System.out.println("Name=" + name + " type=" + type);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

            // add text view
            TextView tv = new TextView(this); // 'this' is unknow here
            tv.setText(name);
            ll.addView(tv);

            EditText et = new EditText(view); // 'view' is what i want to pass but dont know how
            et.setText();
            ll.addView(et);
            it.remove(); 
        }
```

problem is that 'this' is unknown inside onPostExecute function.

i read something about passing the view to the async function but to me it is unclear how to get the view in the firstplace and how to pass it after...

also a lot of options dont seem to work because they are deprecated or are unsafe because the might introduce memory leaks according to the comments.

really lost here.

Comment: use `NewProductActivity.this`, if your asynctask class is non-static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing but You can use `Context context;` and `TextView view;` before onCreate() making it global and then you can call`TextView tv = new TextView(context);` in your method.

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {
Context context=this;
private TextView view;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    view =  (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

}
```

Comment: just setting context did the trick. 

on a side note: view =  (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.content); gave me a cast error

Answer (score 0):

> new loadTemplateAttributes(view).execute();// android studio complains about passing view here

you would have to add constructor to your asynctask, like that:

```
  class loadTemplateAttributes extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap> {
      View view;
      public loadTemplateAttributes(View v) {
          view = v;
      }
```

> TextView tv = new TextView(this); // 'this' is unknow here

from internal class in java, you refer to parent class using `NewProductActivity.this` syntax in your case.

> EditText et = new EditText(view); // 'view' is what i want to pass but dont know how
>               et.setText();

you could use aproach with constructor as I described above, or refer directly to activity view: `NewProductActivity.this.view`. But you would have to make view a class field in your activity.

Advanced: making your activity an internal class instead of static, and also passing views to it, might cause reference leaks and also crashes in case you use view (inside AsyncTask) that was invalidated due to screen rotation. This is especially possible if your AsyncTask is doing network operations. To prevent it always make AsyncTasks static, also if you pass views or activities to them, then wrap  those references in `WeakReference<>`